# JPA/Hibernate Field Mapping for nested json node

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

I am planning store address information in one table itself (ADDRESS table). Since geo is nested node in the json, it will expect entity mapping. But I don't want a separate table for GEO.

How we can include geo.lat and geo.lng as a columns in ADDRESS table itself instead of creating another table.

Sample JSON

```
"address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    }
```

Model Class

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String suite;
    private String city;
    private String zipcode;
    
    // TODO Include geo.lat and geo.lng as fields instead of entity mapping
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

JSON to Java Object Conversion Code Snippet

```
private List<Address> fetchUserDataFromAPI() {
    ResponseEntity<Address[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(apiUrl, Address[].class);
    Address[] addressData = response.getBody();
    return Arrays.asList(addressData);
}
```

Comment: You're looking for Embeddable and Embedded - see https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables

Answer (score 0):

We should use Embeddable and below are the working solution. Thanks to [@racraman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681444/racraman)

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String suite;
    private String city;
    private String zipcode;
    private Geo geo;

    // Getters and Setters
}

@Embeddable
public class Geo {
    @Column(name = "geo_lat")
    private String lat;
    @Column(name = "geo_lng")
    private String lng;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: Great - glad you got it working